# Round Up a double to int

Tags: c#, math, double, int, approximation

I have a number ("double") from int/int (such as 10/3).

What's the best way to Approximation by Excess and convert it to int on C#?

Comment: What is 'Approximation by Excess' ?

Comment: Uhm...maybe I don't know how to call it in english? :) Well, if you have 0.2->1; 0.8->1...and so on..."round" to the next int?

Comment: Do you mean `(int)Math.Ceiling(x)`?

Comment: Oh...it's Round Up! Sorry, thanks :)

Comment: Should -1.5 round to -1 or -2?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Are you asking about [System.Math.Ceiling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx4t0t48.aspx)?

```
Math.Ceiling(0.2) == 1
Math.Ceiling(0.8) == 1
Math.Ceiling(2.6) == 3
Math.Ceiling(-1.4) == -1
```

Comment: Math.Ceiling(-1.4)==-2 -- what language is that ?  Tell me it's name so that I can shun it like the plague.

Comment: Oops, I screwed that up. I looked it up, but I misread the example.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark - well, in C# expression "Math.Ceiling(-1.4)==-2" is correct and basically returns false ;-)

Comment: Seeing how Math.Ceiling returns a decimal and not an int, then no, but OP has accepted this as the answer anyway for some reason.

Answer (score 14):

```
int scaled = (int)Math.Ceiling( (double) 10 / 3 ) ;
```

Comment: I think you need to cast it for this to work.. i.e. `int scaled = (int)Math.Ceiling( (double 10 / 3 );`

Answer (score 2):

By "Approximation by Excess", I assume you're trying to "round up" the number of type double. So, @Doug McClean's "ceiling" method works just fine.

Here is a note:
If you start with `double x = 0.8;` and you do the type conversion by `(int)x;` you get `0`. Or, if you do `(int)Math.Round(x);` you get `1`. 
If you start with `double y = 0.4;` and you do the type conversion by `(int)y;` you get `0`. Or, if you do `(int)Math.Round(y);` you get `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider 2.42 , you can say it's 242/100 btw you can simplify it to 121/50 .