# Convert double to round up using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I want to convert the double value to round up value. That means if a number 12.2 means it converted to 13. How can i convert this using c#

Comment: Ps. Possible duplicat of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295629/round-up-a-double-to-int

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple:

```
int result = (int)Math.Ceiling(value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `System.Math.Ceiling` is nice. 
Example:

```
int output = (int)Math.Ceiling(12.2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`System.Math.Ceiling`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx4t0t48.aspx) method, which does the job

Answer (score 0):

Using `Math.Ceiling` is the simplest way:

```
double input = 12.2;
int output = (int)Math.Ceiling(input);
textBox1.Text = output.ToString(); //if you want to show it in a textBox
```